# Magento Check which Admingrid is loaded

Tags: php, html, magento

i want to check wich grid is currently loaded in the Catalog->Product->Edit-Menu.
The reason for this is, that i have to add a new Button to the "Related Items"-Grid and i must ensure, that the Dropdown is only loaded when the "Related items"-Grid is loaded.

Can anybody give me some advice or tip?

Best regards
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get easily by url string, you can track the class. If you are not familiar with this then use this extension,

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

You can track easily